# Dismiss iOS context menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have added another option to the default context menu. Copy / Send
When the Send option is selected it runs a JavaScript. however the context menu remains visible. How can I disable it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Just use method of `UIMenuController`:

```
[menu setMenuVisible:NO animated:YES];
```

Implement it in SendMenuItemTouched method.
Did you try this?